# Esc button works with .trigger(); only when I click on any element first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I created a simple function which displays stuff inside the iFrame which is located (the iFrame) inside of another element (`#icontent`). Easy. Now I want to close the iFrame and surrounding element using either button created inside of the iFrame or by pressing ESC button. First is easy as well but second works in a strange way.
That's my code:

```
jQuery('.slider-wrapper').on('click','.hide',function() {
    parent.top.jQuery('#icontent').fadeOut(200);
    setTimeout(function(){
        parent.top.jQuery('#mainFrame').attr('src','about:blank');
    }, 250);
});
jQuery(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { jQuery('.hide').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

When clicking `.hide` button it closes the div my iFrame is within. But when I press ESC (which is supposed to simulate clicking the button) it works but only if I click on any element first (except of mentioned button), if I don't click anywhere first it does nothing. Is there any explanation to that?

Thanks and regards, Dan.

Comment: Well if the document does not have focus than the key listener will not be able to listen... Maybe add the listener outside of the iframe also where the keypress is being fired.

Comment: well I changed the code to:
`jQuery(document).keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
   jQuery('.hide').trigger('click');
   jQuery('#mainFrame').contents().find('.hide').trigger('click');
     }
 });`
and it works, but isn't it some kind of workaround instead of the piece of nice and clean code?

Comment: Change the code to what?

Comment: Sorry, hit enter to soon..

Comment: You can bind it from the iframe and unbind it when you close it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that, didn't get that far with jQuery..